# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getBottom()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listview-adapter

It's working fine when I build and run it. But I'm getting this error when I relaunch the app remotely.

this is the only place where I used `views`. It's in `ListAdapter`.

I looked around on both Google and StackOverflow and I have found some information. However, I have not got it to work. Now I hope that I can get help with my code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getBottom()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:829)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:888)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1958)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2991)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:888)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1075)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3394)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1911)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8526)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:974)
```

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if(getItem(position)!= null) {
            title = getItem(position).getText();
            date = getItem(position).getDate();
            hour = getItem(position).getHour();
            minute = getItem(position).getMinute();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView descpView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            TextView dateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            titleView.setText(title);
            descpView.setText(hour + ":" + minute);
            dateView.setText(formatter.format(date));
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getBottom()' on a null object reference

Some view is getting null causing `NullPointerException` when calling `getBottom()` on that view.

So, as the app runs locally without this issue; but not remotely, so the answer will be a kind of a guess.

**Assumption 1:**  `getView` returns a null value.

**Reason:** `convertView` is marked as `@Nullable`, so it can be `null` from the beginning, and can remain null if the condition `if(getItem(position)!= null)` is not met; and therefore `getView()` can return a `null View`.

**Recommendation:** you need to make sure that `getView` can't return null value by setting the `convertView` value outside the `if` condition like the below snippet.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (converView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    }
```

**Assumption 2:**   `convertView` is null from this expression  `convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);`

**Reason:** You didn't provide from where you got the `resource` argument you pass to `inflate()`; maybe it's a variable value that can change in multiple values; one of which can be null; and therefore making `convertView` null as well.

**Recommendation:**

If the `resource` is not changeable, you can hardcode it by setting its value to say `R.layout.list_row`; where `list_row` is the xml layout of your list item.

And If it's changeable, then debug its value to make sure it can't be null by any means.

Comment: @NoorHossain just modified it

Comment: Thanks Your second Assumption works for me, then one question, so, what is best practice to send the resource layout as a parameter ?

Comment: @NoorHossain welcome.. It depends on the code... Generally speaking you can pass initial  value to the adapter constructor and save it into a local field .. And create a setter for this field and call it  whenever  need to change the value.

This value should be integer that refer to a layout restore file.. If theres no a layout resource for this value then a NPE will be raised