# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when installed from Play Store, but working fine locally

Tags: android, pointers, exception, nullpointerexception, null

I am facing an issue with one of my live app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apps24x7.app.publichealth&hl=en_IE, When I am installing the app from play store it crashes after splash screen, However, its working fine in Offline mode, when installed through android studio.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
      at com.apps24x7.app.publichealth.Adapters.ChapterGridAdapter.getView (ChapterGridAdapter.java:4)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView (AbsListView.java:3180)
      at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure (GridView.java:1102)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:715)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:461)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:715)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:461)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6967)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure (ConstraintLayout.java:23)
      at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.a (BasicMeasure.java:116)
      at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren (BasicMeasure.java:48)
      at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure (BasicMeasure.java:48)
      at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:48)
      at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem (ConstraintLayout.java:48)
      at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure (ConstraintLayout.java:48)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6967)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:18)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java:18)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure (DrawerLayout.java:3)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6967)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
      at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:154)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6967)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1514)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:806)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:685)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6967)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6967)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1514)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:806)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:685)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6967)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure (DecorView.java:909)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:23410)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:3017)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1997)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2286)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1863)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:8072)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:911)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:723)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:658)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7000)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:441)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Hammered this as a dupe of the NPE canonical as it lacks a [mcve]. If you post an MCVE and it still indicates this isn't a dupe, I'll reopen it

Comment: Please have a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62088733/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-int-android-vi/62092170#62092170)

Answer (score -1):

I can't post a comment yet, did you enabled proguard? make sure you add all of your models to proguard rules. And please provide your question with your source code.

```
-keep class com.yourapps.yourpackage.model.** { *; }
```